# Expected Exception but nothing was raised Rails Mailer (the raising-exception method seems not to be called)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm having RSpec which expect some exception to be raised. However, when invoking the method, I got error: `expected Exception but nothing was raised`

my code:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe ReportMailer, type: :mailer do
  let(:csv_file) { "data\n1\n2" }
  let(:filename) { 'dummy.csv' }
  let(:options) do
    {
      filename: filename,
      to: user.email,
      subject: "Transaction Report - #{filename}"
    }
  end

   it 'raise error' do
     expect do
       ReportMailer.notify(options, nil)
     end.to raise_error(SomeExceptions::InvalidFile)
   end

end
```

The problem is that if I just use normal `expect` call, let's say

```
expect(described_class.notify(dummy_options, nil)).to eq 1
```

RSpec show failure/error that I expect before:

```
Failures:

  1) ReportMailer raise error
     Failure/Error: raise SomeExceptions::InvalidFile

     SomeExceptions::InvalidFile:
       The file is invalid
     # ./app/mailers/report_mailer.rb:5:in `notify'
     # ./spec/mailers/report_mailer_spec.rb:37:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

My notify method is below:

```
require 'some_cms_exceptions'

class ReportMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def notify(options, csv)
    binding.pry
    raise SomeExceptions::InvalidFile

    validate(options)

    attachments[options[:filename]] = { mime_type: 'text/csv', content: csv }
    mail(to: options[:to], subject: options[:subject])
  end

  private

  def validate(options)
    raise SomeExceptions::InvalidMailOptions unless !options[:to].blank? && !options[:filename].blank?
  end
end
```

I then put `binding.pry` in notify method and found out that:
if we use `expect` block, i.e. `expect.{...}.to`, notify method is not executed.
But if we use normal `expect`, i.e. `expect(...).to` ,notify method is executed.

May I know why it behaves like this ? Because other SO questions showed it works by using expect block.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At line 5 you are raising `SomeExceptions::InvalidFile` exception while you are expecting different error in the expectation block

```
raise_error(SomeExceptions::InvalidMailOptions)
```

either you replace the exception you are expected or catch all exception using just `raise_error` without passing any error class(not recommended but for sake of testing).

Comment: Thanks for the note @amit-patel.

Sorry that actually I manually edit the code. I tried using raise_error only, but it's still ` but nothing was raised`

Comment: Somehow running expect in block did not execute the notify method. Is there any special condition in Rails? maybe due to mailer etc?

Comment: You need to call `deliver_now` in order to send email so it will look like `ReportMailer.notify(options, nil).deliver_now` in your spec

Comment: Hi Amit, it worked!

May I know why adding deliver_now make it work pls?

btw, how tp set your comment as the answer? Sorry SO newbie here

Answer (score 0):

The answer is as commented by @amit-patel, we need to add `deliver_now` to really execute `mailer` RSpec test case.

```
it 'should send email ' do
 expect { ReportMailer.notify(options, nil).deliver_now }.to raise_error(SomeExceptions::InvalidMailOptions)
end
```